# Creating a python module

Tags: python, module

I create two files: *test.py* and *test1234.py*

*test.py* contains:

```
import test1234
t = test1234.test()
```

*test1234.py* contains:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
```

When put in the same directory, `python test.py` runs without error.

However, if I create a directory *test1234* and put *test1234.py* and a blank ***init**.py* in this directory, `python test.py` gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'

What do I need to do for *test.py* to be able to see the `test` class in *test1234.py*?

Comment: Downvoters care to weigh in? Is my question not clear enough? Is it unacceptable that I didn't understand how python imports work? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import it through the package, or put it in `__init__.py`.

```
import test1234.test1234
t = test1234.test1234.test()
```

Comment: Put what, specifically, in `__init__.py`? I wish to only have `import test1234` in `test.py`.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that you can do `from test1234 import test` in `__init__.py`.

Comment: Be careful with that last one though; consider renaming either the package or the submodule.